# How do i add rows to specific class?

Tags: android, parse-platform

That's my code:

```
    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("col1", "sharon");
    testObject.put("col2", "michael");
    testObject.put("col3", "john");
    try {
        testObject.save();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    ParseObject testObject2 = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("col1", "ron");
    testObject.put("col2", "ted");
    testObject.put("col3", "dave");
    try {
        testObject2.save();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem is  - when i save the second object of "TestObject" class , it has undefined values in parse.com's data browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: typo. `testObject` -> `testObject2`

Comment: I don't understand. what's the specific syntax ?

Comment: In the second section you write `testObject.put("col1", "ron");` instead of `testObject2.put("col1", "ron");`

Answer (score 1):

You had some typos. In the second object creation, you used `put` with `testObject` instead of `testObject2`.

```
ParseObject testObject2 = new ParseObject("TestObject");
testObject2.put("col1", "ron");  //This line had a typo
testObject2.put("col2", "ted");  //This line had a typo
testObject2.put("col3", "dave"); //This line had a typo
try {
    testObject2.save();
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```